# Detecting/recording AS3 "stop the world" GC pauses

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, garbage-collection

**Context**: a large AS3 application that *may* be suffering from frequent but unpredictable "stop the world" garbage collection pauses. When one does strike it can take 30s or more to conclude.

This does not occur in testing, however it may in production.

**Question**: Is there any logging available from the Flash VM that might be used to detect and record such events? I am drawing on my experience with Java here. I have read widely on the functioning of the Flash GC machinery (reference-counting with mark/sweep), but I'm looking for some real telemetry from an application running in the wild as I understand that a mark/sweep GC event can "stop the world".

Comment: It's no GC fault but yours, too many object creations and no right way to qualify them for GC. Use pooling or create less objects.

Comment: You misunderstand. I seek to establish **if** the observed pauses are caused by GC.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct. The garbage collector pauses application execution.

> The Flash Runtime garbage collector algorithm runs incrementally while marking memory in use. It pauses application execution when collecting unused portions of memory. The pause that occurs as the incremental collection cycle finishes can be longer than desired and can be observable or audible in some programs.

*from [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent())*

## Check if garbage collector did run

As to my knowledge there is no direct way to know if GC ran. But it is possible to have a test function execute on `ENTER_FRAME` and check if the garbage has been collected since the last function call. Effectively since the last frame.

Through a `Dictionary` which can store weak referenced keys it is possible to see if an object has been collected. If this is the case garbage collection must have run. In the following class I create a new object, to later check if it has been collected.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.utils.Dictionary;

    public class GCTest
    {
        private static var dict:Dictionary = null;
        
        public static function didGCRun():Boolean
        {
            if ( dict == null ) {
                dict = new Dictionary(true);
            }
            
            var hasKeys:Boolean = false;
            
            for ( var obj:* in dict ) {
                hasKeys = true;
                break;
            }
            
            if ( hasKeys ) {
                return false;
            }
            else {
                dict[new Sprite()] = null;
                return true;
            }
        }       
    }
}
```

By checking on each frame you will know if gc stroke

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame);

private function onEnterFrame(event:Event):void
{
    var gcRan:Boolean = GCTest.didGCRun();
}
```

## Memory usage

You can also monitor garbage collection by checking memory usage. The documentation advises to use [`System.freeMemory()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#freeMemory)

> The amount of memory (in bytes) that is allocated to Adobe Flash Player or Adobe AIR and that is not in use. This unused portion of allocated memory (System.totalMemory) fluctuates as garbage collection takes place. Use this property to monitor garbage collection.

I would use this value in conjunction with [`System.totalMemoryNumber()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#totalMemoryNumber)

## Validate execution times

In conjunction with the other methods it might be helpful to record the actual frame rate or the execution time of code blocks. This can be achieved by storing the programs "uptime" in a variable and comparing it at a later point.

Use [`getTimer()`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/package.html#getTimer())

> For a Flash runtime processing ActionScript 3.0, this method returns the number of milliseconds that have elapsed since the Flash runtime virtual machine for ActionScript 3.0 (AVM2) started.

```
var startTime:int = getTimer();
// execution or frame change
var executionTime:int = getTimer() - startTime;
```

when used on each frame you can compare this to [`stage.frameRate`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#frameRate) and check for discrepancies.

## Advise garbage collector to execute

A possibility to mitigate your pauses might be to advise the garbage collector to execute manually. [`System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent(imminence:Number = 0.75)`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent()) will pause program execution if the actual imminence is higher than the arguments value.

> Imminence is defined as how far through marking the collector believes it is, and therefore how close it is to triggering a collection pause. The imminence argument to this function is a threshold: the garbage collector will be invoked only if the actual imminence exceeds the threshold value. Otherwise, this call returns immediately without taking action.
>
> By calling this function with a low imminence value, the application indicates that it is willing to accept that a relatively large amount of marking must be completed. A high imminence value, on the other hand, indicates that the application should be paused only if marking is nearly complete. Typically, pauses are longer in the former case than in the latter.
>
> **imminence**:Number (default = 0.75) — A number between 0 and 1, where 0 means less imminent and 1 means most imminent. Values less than 0 default to 0.25. Values greater than 1.0 default to 1.0. NaN defaults to 0.75

*from [reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/system/System.html#pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent())*

Answer (score 0):

[Adobe Scout](https://creative.adobe.com/products/scout) is a nice tool to profile AS3 projects.

Comment: The problem only manifests "in the wild" where use of Scout is impractical - sadly.

Comment: .. is it possible to output a Scout telemetry *file* from a running application, in such circumstances?

Comment: Scout automatically detects when you launch an AIR app or a SWF in a browser, therefore it is possible to watch real-time telemetry data from a running release quality app. Though, in order to get full telemetry data you will need either compile the app using -advanced-telemetry=true compiler flag or process compiled SWF file to support that using [this tool](http://renaun.com/blog/2012/12/enable-advanced-telemetry-on-flex-or-old-swfs-with-swf-scount-enabler/)

Comment: Scout is very powerful indeed, even if you can't reproduce 30 seconds freezes, it's highly probable that you will spot issues in allocations made by your application, otherwise it would not have such problems with the GC. GC activity does not come out of nowhere, such freezes must be caused by a huge amount of allocations.

Answer (score 0):

You can use :

```
setInterval( function()
{
    trace(System.totalMemory);
},1000);
```

whenever garbage collector works and it's busy the amount of memory changes a lot. if you see the memory changes and at the same time your program paused or has glitches so it has been caused by GC.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, what is your production environment ?
flash player, AIR desktop, AIR mobile ?
Your app is supposed to perform computation heavy tasks ?

30+ seconds of garbage collecting seems huge, but if the pauses are indeed caused by the garbage collector, logging it will not help you much, except confirming your supposition.

The first thing I would do, is extensively test your app with telemetry
If you see any sign of abnormal activity of the GC (big red spikes, or a permanent gc noise that is more than a couple of percents on every frame), activate memory allocation telemetry and find/eliminate bottlenecks in memory instantiations. Just remember that even freed allocations have an impact on gc so use pooling, and be very strict on allocations that occur on every frames, even a few allocations will have a significant impact.
Beware that parsing big xml or json files is very heavy on allocations.

Once you have made sure that your application is using memory properly, check (or let your testers/beta testers/users check) if the problem is still here or if it's less frequent or even has disapeared.

If it does't work, you will have at least improved the performance and memory footprint of your app in the first place
Don't you have more information on the nature of the pause and have you considered other options than GC ? Maybe the probleme is not where you search it :
You can try catching and logging all errors with [UncaughtErrorEvent](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/UncaughtErrorEvent.html#includeExamplesSummary) (then use URLLoader to post the error stack to your error logging service). It could help you detect hard to reproduce errors in production, for instance:

- stuck in a function: should throw a ScriptTimeoutError after 15 seconds (code #1502) which will open a popup in flash player debugger.
- any other Error will interrupt the whole stack which may put your application in an unresponsive state. Maybe some long timeout is making it responsive again ?

BTW How do you know that you application is experiencing 30+ seconds freeze if you are not logging it and have never reproduced it ? If it is a bug reported by end users, try to get more informations (get their os, flash player version, pattern...) If it's frequent, you should be able to reproduce it.